# Download of android studio 3 RC 1

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I've decided to upload my alfa app to google play .....
After harsh strugle with it I passed an automatic test.
And failed in all mobiles .... a simple anko toast was the culprit I remove it
Then I noticed that my 1.2 MB app turned into a mamooth of 18 MB
So I turn to enable minify ... shrink resources and so one in gradle
The next trimed version once upload proveed definitelly slim, in fact allmost everything was removed, so nothing worked.
Whent back to previous one and on the next day I've recived a notification on my android-studio 3 telling me that the Release Candidate 1 was available, read release notes and found

Issue #65519025: Missing classes in APK
Issue #65829618: Incremental builds fail when enabling resource shrinking

apparently I was saved, but no when I click the download button I get a link to my current version, mistakes are everywhere .....

Comment: You can’t update android Studio 3.0 RC 1 from previous version. You need to download standalone installations file to install android studio. One more note if you importing / opening old project then first clean build then use project.

Comment: Thank you, but the only download I can see is Android studio beta 7 which already have, can you point me to the android 3.0 RC 1 download? I just can't find it! thank you so much

Comment: I posted links in answer have a look

Answer (score 2):

try it
https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html?hl=en

I found it using this link.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio cant be updated via delta update. You will need to download entire build from this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Than you so much, I can't understand why you can see the links and I can't, maybe it's related to the fact that I'm in Spain, our job it's really a never ending story, good luck to you and many thanks!!

Comment: Where is the link to this page? I can't see the RC1 from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Comment: @webo80 are you behind proxy? check the image snapshot to verify the legit url. There is also a radio button to display all the versions.

Comment: Just to inform you that right now RC 1 has become available in my country, let's suffer it!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Download Android Studio Preview from following links

Android Studio Preview: [Link 1](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html)

Android Studio Archives: [Link 2](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html)

Android Studio 3.0 RC 1 
Windows:

[Windows (64-bit)](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.16/android-studio-ide-171.4392136-windows.zip)

[Windows (32-bit)](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.16/android-studio-ide-171.4392136-windows32.zip)

[Linux](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.16/android-studio-ide-171.4392136-linux.zip)

[Mac](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.16/android-studio-ide-171.4392136-mac.zip)

Comment: I still don't see any android studio 3.0 RC 1 download, but just android studio 3.0 beta 7

Comment: Which OS (Operating System) are you using ?

Comment: the infamous windows10

Comment: Download Links Added for windows in answer

Answer (score 0):

The download link I speculated

windows： https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.16/android-studio-ide-171.4392136-windows.zip

mac：https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.16/android-studio-ide-171.4392136-mac.zip